# Impala: when refresh tables?

Tags: refresh, impala

using impala I noticed a deterioration in performance when I perform several times truncate and insert operations in internal tables.
The question is: can refreshing the tables avoid the problem?
So far I have used refresh only for external tables every time I copied files to hdfs to be loaded into the tables themselves.

Many thanks in advance!
Moreno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `compute stats` instead of `refresh`.

`Refresh` is normally used when you add a data file or change something in table metadata - like add column or partition /change column etc. It quickly reloads the metadata. There is another related command `invalidate metadata` but this is more expensive than refresh and will force impala to reload metadata when table is called in next query.

`compute stats` - This is to compute stats of the table or columns when around 30% data changed. Its expensive operation but effective when you do frequent truncate and load.

Comment: Thanks Roy, so if I truncate a table every day and then insert new data, should I run the compute stats after the insert (or is it equivalent to do it at a different time, for example before the truncate?)

Comment: yes, after every insert logically. But if you think data isnt changing much, you should do it every day end of day etc.